# Sql Query Between two double values

Tags: mysql, sql, floating-point

I am using a sql query to fetch all shops between two latitudes and longitudes. The query is given below

```
    SELECT ID FROM venues WHERE
(latitude BETWEEN 41.439998626708984 AND 41.939998626708984 ) AND
(longitude BETWEEN 2.1800000667572021 and 2.6800000667572021);
```

But this query is not returning any values where as the same query with two precision in floating values is returning the result. That query is given below

```
SELECT ID FROM yupii_eventlist_venues WHERE
(latitude BETWEEN 41.43 AND 41.93) AND
(longitude BETWEEN 2.18 and 2.68);
```

I am using MySQl. Could someone help me to make this right.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you typing in those values manually or through another language like Java or .NET?

Comment: @Jeanne: I am trying this manually. But this query is supposed to be run in c# .net

Comment: Is that second example supposed to be 41.44 and 41.94 or did you mistype it?

Comment: I think this is happening because the first query is converting 41.4399 to 41.44. And i don't have any entry for that value. Is there any way to prevent that conversion

Comment: Those numbers are very precise - 0.00001 is about 1 meter, so your coordinates have an accuracy of about 0.01 nanometers!

Comment: Well I think the second query will return a venue with a latitude of 41.435 but the first one won't. What are the latitude and longitude of the venue that you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks all. It was a floating point issue. I changed the fields to double and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup your fields as floats with specific rules.  I use `float(10,6)` for Lats and Longs.